# Is rowversion unique across the database? Or per table?

Tags: sql-server

If I have a rowversion on two different tables in a database, are they guaranteed to be unique across both tables? If not, is there any way to set this behaviour?

I have a view that joins two tables together, I'm wondering if this behaviour is guaranteed, so that I could take the largest row number from either table, to form a rowversion for the view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx), it '**should**' be unique across all tables in a database.

Here is the '**should**' part - there is a caveat in the documentation:

> Duplicate rowversion values can be generated by using the SELECT INTO
>   statement in which a rowversion column is in the SELECT list. We do
>   not recommend using rowversion in this manner.

And here is a summary of the information in the link:

> Each database has a counter that is incremented for each insert or
>   update operation that is performed on a table that contains a
>   rowversion column within the database. This counter is the database
>   rowversion. This tracks a relative time within a database, not an
>   actual time that can be associated with a clock. A table can have only
>   one rowversion column. Every time that a row with a rowversion column
>   is modified or inserted, the incremented database rowversion value is
>   inserted in the rowversion column.